# Apache, .htaccess: FilesMatch matches URIs or real file names?

Tags: apache, http, .htaccess

This is about Apache, and in particular `.htaccess` directives.

Let's suppose that `/index.htm` exists.

I want to have a whitelist of files allowed to be accessed (only `.htm`), so I've come up with this:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
<FilesMatch "\.htm$">
  Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

What I see is that when requesting `www.domain.com/index.htm` all works fine, but when requesting just `www.domain.com` (empty URI) I get a 403 response (of course I should get the default `index.htm` instead).

After some testing I've discovered that it's because the empty string is not allowed by FilesMatch, so I'm wondering if I have understood well: **[question #1a]** can I say that FilesMatch matches the URI and **not** directly the real filename (the one in the filesystem)?

After this I have tried to rewrite the empty string with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ index.htm [L]
```

with no luck, so **[question #1b]** can I say that FilesMatch denies access **before** any rewrite or am I doing something wrong?

In the end the only working solution I've come up with is including the empty string in FilesMatch's regexp:

```
<FilesMatch "(^|\.htm)$">
```

**[question #2]** Is this really the best, or even the only way to solve this problem? I can't find my solution around in the web, so I fear I'm doing something wrong from the very beginning...

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your main question and question 1a, FilesMatch matches on file paths, use LocationMatch to match urls.

This is documented here : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/sections.html#file-and-web

Your question 1b, mod_rewrite can rewrite before authorization start, as stated here : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#InternalAPI

It's not clear to me why your rewrite rule didn't work, however i usually write :

```
RewriteRule ^/$ index.htm [L]
```

IIRC because there is always a "/", both on the server url and inside a folder, but I might be wrong on this point.